# multiplication of empty list in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, scheme

Why in lisp (Emacs Lisp and Scheme as I know) construction like `(*)` returns `1`?

What I multiply here? How can I call this function `*` without arguments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a mathematical convention: the [product of an empty sequence of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is one, by definition; note that one is the identity element for multiplication (1×*a* = *a*×1 = *a*). This is convenient because you can call `*` with a variable number of arguments without worrying about the case where there are no arguments present.

Similarly, the sum of an empty sequence of numbers is zero, the identity element for addition. Try issuing `(+)` at your Lisp prompt.

Comment: `(*(+(*)(*)(*))(+(*)(*)(*)(*)(*)(*))(+(*)(*(+(*)(*)(*)(*))(+(*)(*)(*))(+(*)(*)(*)))))`

Comment: @EliBarzilay: is that the sexpr of the Beast?

Comment: (Yes, and the minimal length version too...)

Answer (score 4):

It's a property inherited from mathematics. It's like *addition*, you can add together any number of numbers, with the special case that adding no numbers together give you the sum zero.

Likewise for multiplication, if you multiply an arbitrary number of numbers, you will get the product. To get this to work for no numbers, 1 is used as the base value (which has some fancy name in mathematics, which I have forgotten many years ago).

So, do you have any practical use for this in a programming language. Yes, as you can call a functions like `+` and `*` with arbitrary number of arguments, I would say yes. For example:

```
(apply '+ '(2 3 4)) => 9
(apply '+ '(2 3))   => 5
(apply '+ '(2))     => 2
(apply '+ '())      => 0

(apply '* '(2 3 4)) => 24
(apply '* '(2 3))   => 6
(apply '* '(2))     => 2
(apply '* '())      => 1
```

Comment: Note: in Scheme, you must remove the `'` (ie, `quote`) in front of the operator for the examples to run. So for example, `(apply + '())` instead of `(apply '+ '())`.